# What is the order of the processing of modules in IIS?

Tags: iis, rewrite, request-filtering

We have an `URL Rewrite` rule and a `Request Filter`. Which one evaluates first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may depend on your configuration.

To see the execution order of modules on your server, enable `Failed Request Tracing` for the site and then review the `Request Details` or `Compact View` in the log files.

Comment: The question is moot now. The manager thought that the Url Rewrite would also force the query string to lower case.